# Inserting a new div in parent div and simultanously ending it

Tags: jquery, html

My code is like this

```
<div class="tab-1">
 <a class="parent-category" href="#">Link1</a>
 <a class="child-category first" href="#">Link2 </a>
 <a class="child-category" href="#">Link3 </a>
 <a class="child-category" href="#">Link4</a>
 <a class="child-category end" href="#">Link5</a>

 <a class="parent-category" href="#"> LinkA </a>
 <a class="parent-category" href="#"> LinkB </a>
 <a class="child-category first" href="#">LinkB1</a>
 <a class="child-category end" href="#">LinkB2</a>
</div>
```

I want a jquery procedure to insert a new div "tab2" and end its parent div when class .end encounters for the first time.
As below

```
<div class="tab-1">
 <a class="parent-category" href="#">Link1</a>
 <a class="child-category first" href="#">Link2 </a>
 <a class="child-category" href="#">Link3 </a>
 <a class="child-category" href="#">Link4</a>
 <a class="child-category end" href="#">Link5</a>
 </div><div class="tab-2">
 <a class="parent-category" href="#"> LinkA </a>
 <a class="parent-category" href="#"> LinkB </a>
 <a class="child-category first" href="#">LinkB1</a>
 <a class="child-category end" href="#">LinkB2</a>
</div>
```

I have tried after();, append(); , before(); . But every time i write

```
$(this).after('</div><div class="tab-2">');
```

it is rendered on browsers as "`<div class="tab-2"></div>`", which i dont want.
Looking forward for a solution

Comment: please find an answer below

Answer (score 1):

Like collapsar says, you need to operate on the DOM elements.

Here's one way you could do it

```
// first create an empty `div` with class tab-2
$('.tab-1').after("<div class='tab-2'></div>");

// Find the first element with class .end, detach everything after it and put it in the next div
$('.tab-1 .end').first().nextAll().detach().appendTo('.tab-2');
```

See it live in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sRS9g/).

EDIT : anticipating that you might want to do create more than one div, [here's a loop](http://jsfiddle.net/sRS9g/1/) that will sort this out :

```
var i=1;
while ($('.tab-'+i+' .end').first().nextAll().length > 0)
{
    j = i+1;
    $('.tab-'+i).after("<div class='tab-"+j+"'></div>");
    $('.tab-'+i+' .end').first().nextAll().detach().appendTo('.tab-'+j);
    i += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not the way jquery works.

it operates on the dom abstraction (trees), not on the lexical representation.

you *can* act the way you want by performing string replace operations on the lexical level:

```
var textual = $('#parent-div').html();
textual = textual.replace(/<some_pattern>/g, "<some_substitution>");
$('#parent-div').html(textual);
```

obviously, this practice doesn't scale well wrt to readability and maintainability.

Comment: @RoyMcCrossan: thanks for your hint. as the OP wished to have a jquery procedure, it is kind of an answer imho. however, it denies his intended approach so i have added a jquery-compatible solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you...here is a working fiddle: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ARGBF/)

JS:

```
$(function(){
    var newDiv = $('<div class="tab-2"></div>"');
    newDiv.insertAfter($('.child-category.end').first());
    newDiv.nextAll().appendTo(newDiv);
    newDiv.insertAfter($('.tab-1'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit messy but does what you want, currently it is fixed for `tabs` as class for the new `div`'s but you can fix that perhaps with another argument in the function.
Working here on many `end`'s rather than just the two in your example which all the other current answers can only handle. http://jsfiddle.net/VUmyD/

```
function splitContentsOf(selector) {
    iterator = 1;
    firstEndCount = 0;
    reset = false;
    $(selector).children().each(function (index1, child) {
        if ($(child).hasClass('end')) {
            if (firstEndCount == 0) {
                firstEndCount = index1;
            } else if (firstEndCount > 0) {
                var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
                iterator++;
                $(newDiv).addClass('tab-' + iterator);
                $(selector).children().each(function (index2, child2) {
                    if (index2 > firstEndCount && !reset) {
                        if ($(child2).hasClass('end')) {
                            reset = true;
                        }
                        $(child2).appendTo(newDiv);
                    }
                });
                reset = false;
                if (iterator > 2) {
                    $(oldDiv).after(newDiv);
                } else {
                    $(selector).after(newDiv);
                }
                oldDiv = newDiv;
            }
        }
    });
}

splitContentsOf('.tab-1');
```